# How to transform the CompletableFuture response

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

Context: I have a client app which consumes an API. I want to call this API is async way (using `java.net.http.HttpClient`) and once I receive this data then I want to model the response because it can have either error or actual data in `java.net.http.HttpResponse<String>`. So it will be good if I cloud transform to model class `ExecutionResult` so that my client app can use this class where ever it wants depending of either error or actual data.

So the API returns `CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>>`:

```
CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> response = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .executor(executorService)
                .build()
                .sendAsync(apiRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Now I want to transform `HttpResponse<String>` to some another class, lets say ExecutionResult.
So basically it should return `CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult>`

For this, I have written like this but I am not sure this is the correct approach

```
CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> fututeExecutionResult = new CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult>();
fututeExecutionResult = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<ExecutionResult>() {
            @Override
            public ExecutionResult get() {
                ExecutionResult result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse<String> httpres = response.get();
                    JsonNode json;
                    try {
                        json = new ObjectMapper().readTree(httpres.body());
                        result = new ExecutionResult(json);
                        if(result.hasError())
                            throw new DataFetchingException(result.getErrorMessage());
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
                return result;
            }
        });
```

The model class

```
  public ExecutionResult(JsonNode response) {
    this.response = response;
    if (response.has(ERROR)) {
        dataFetchingException = new DataFetchingException(getErrorMessage());
    }
}

public boolean hasData() {
    return response.has(DATA) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}

public JsonNode getData() {
    return response.get(DATA);
}

public boolean hasError() {
    return response.has(ERROR) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}

public JsonNode getError() {
    return response.get(ERROR);
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return response.get(ERROR).findValue(MESSAGE).asText();
}

public DataFetchingException getGraphQLError() {
    return this.dataFetchingException;
}
```

Could you please suggest any better approach?

Comment: The ExecutionResult is missing a few lines. Please add those.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [thenApply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) method in CompletableFuture?

```
HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .executor(executorService)
    .build()
    .sendAsync(apiRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
    .thenApply(new Function<HttpResponse<String>, ExecutionResult>() {
        public ExecutionResult apply(HttpResponse<String> response) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Your `ExecutionResult` is a decorator for the JSON document. I dont' like this approach because it closely couples the ExecutionResult into the JSON. I prefer separating data conversion into distinct classes, [Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) if you will, that remove the responsibility of data format conversion from the data container objects. Then you can more easily produce ExecutionResults from different input data. If you had this kind of a converter class, you could use it directly in the `thenApply` method instead of writing unreusable anonymous classes.

Would it be possible to return the exceptions that are caught as ExecutionResults with an error status? Returning a null on transportation error seems like a bit of a code smell in this case, as you already have a mechanism for transmitting request errors to the client.

The `ExecutionResult` creating the `DataFetchingException` seems like an unnecessary helper method. That doesn't seem like it belongs in a data container object. And storing it in a variable for later use, even if nobody needs it, seems wasteful.